# Why does this Cube look like a Rhombicuboctahedron trapped inside a cube?

Tags: mesh, faces

I am very new to blender, just been working on making a donut from the blender guru and messing around a bit on my own so far. This has happened to me a few times now where my cubes and planes will like- i dunno, subdivide(?) themselves inside their shape.[image: This is what the the cube looks like with what I'm talking about]
This is in Edit mode, object mode it just looks like the Rhombicuboctahedron (had to look that one up lol) on its own.

I tried to look up a solution on my own before posting here since I'm sure this a small thing I just don't know about yet, but couldn't seem to figure out the right search terms, so I apologize if this has been addressed already or anything but I just couldn't seem to get the answer on my own

If I haven't provided enough details please ask me for more, but be very specific as I likely won't have the foggiest what you mean if you just ask for a setting by name
♥

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have a subdivision surface modifier on your cube! This will subdivide the mesh as you model it. You can remove it in the modifiers tab. [image]

Comment: ohhhhh okay, thank you! not sure how that sneaky sub surf got added, but that makes a lot of sense. 

* looks at original post where I literally wrote the word subdivide * 

* feels shame *

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can add a subdivision surface modifier with the shorcut CTRL + 1, CTRL + 2 .. etc, the number being the level of the subdivision. You may have inadvertently triggered this shorcut.

Comment: oh that's super handy! so many nice shortcuts in blender

Thank you!